# When object is passed to an exports function, script fails. When same object is passed directly to function, it passes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function which creates objects from scraped website data. The objects look like this:

```
{ 
  name: 'Object Name',
  baseURL: 'http://xyz123.com',
  mainImg_select: '#item_image a',
  mainImg_ref: 'href',
  moreImg_select: '.extra_images',
  moreImg_ref: 'href',
  one_brand: '',
  urls: [],
  categories:
   [ { name: 'Cat 1',
       url: 'http://xyz123.com/category1' },
     { name: 'Cat 2',
       url: 'http://xyz123.com/category2' },
     { name: 'Cat 3',
       url: 'http://xyz123.com/category3' }
   ] 
}
```

I'm running it through some functions that use the `request` and `cheerio` modules. The `request` function is, somehow, deleting my objects' `categories` property; when logging the object I see `"categories: undefined"` (so the property is still there, just its contents are removed.

What's REALLY bizarre is that this ONLY happens when I'm using an object stored in a variable that is created by my script. If I create the object, log it, then copy and paste it directly into the code (like above except `var object123 = {stuff goes here}`) then my Node script works just fine.

`PrepJSON` is a class which takes a JSON file turns it into an object. To avoid this becoming a massive wall of code, I've pastebin'd it here: http://pastebin.com/Tgx0nnmR

[This doesn’t work](http://pastebin.ca/2404668)

[This works](http://pastebin.ca/2404667)

The only difference is that in one I'm using a returned object from my `prepJSON` function, in the other I'm console.logging that object, running the function, copying the log, putting it in a variable - then magically the script works.

The rest of the object is NOT touched by the script - only the categories, which stores an array of objects. For completeness, here's how the `object.categories` are created in prepJSON. This is the only time a script touches them:

```
storeCats.categories = (function(){
        $('.view-Departments .field-content a').each(function(index){
        storeCats.categories.push({'name': $(this).text(), 'url': $(this).attr('href')}); 
        if(index == $('.view-Departments .field-content a').length -1) {callback(null);} 
    })}
)();
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a global variable that is mutated by something else during the async call.

Comment: @SLaks I thought this too. I've tried renaming everything to very obscure names (`categories` to `cats1` and whatnot) but to no avail.

Comment: @SLaks further, I don't think that would explain the situation here. To clarify, when I paste the object into a variable, the object creation script still runs. Literally the only difference is that the object it spits out isn't being used, and the copy/pasted object (which should be exactly the same) is instead.

Comment: Where is your `obj123` coming from anyway? It's not passed as an argument to `requestHandler`. @SLaks' suggestion about it being a global variable (or, more likely, a recycled variable, doesn't have to be global) that's mutated (not overwritten, but changed) sounds like a reasonable cause, esp. if you're passing around that (global) variable (when the code that's 'filling' `obj123` can still change it).

Comment: @robertklep See above, I've edited in some more code, was trying to keep it brief. The request function is made in a callback that fires only after the object has been created, am I naive in assuming that this means that the preceding script is finished with it?

Comment: @Jascination try putting a `var` before `storeCats = {}` (pastebin code line 6). Without it you're promoting it to a global variable.

Comment: @robertklep Tried it, hasn't fixed it. Something not shown above is that my main script `requires` the `request` module (as well as a few others), which are also required in the pastebin function code. I've given them different variable names though so they shouldn't conflict.

Comment: @Jascination regarding your Pastebin code: your second function passed to `async.series` doesn't call the callback (line 27); the code on line 35 does an assign, not a check; your error handler for `request` doesn't call `cbfunct`;

Comment: You should probably refer to `obj123` as `store` within `requestHandler` because that's how you refer to it in the function declaration. if that doesn't solve some mysterious scoping issue, I would guess that cheerio is misbehaving? I dont see anything else that would modify obj123

Comment: @robertklep Line 27 (the `eval` code) is a function stored in a string in JSON, which has `callback()` at the end of it. Line 35 you are correct, although this didn't change anything. The error handler isn't supposed to call `cbfunct`, that's the callback signal and I want the code to break if the objects aren't created properly at that point.Even if I do a bunch of other stuff to the object beforehand, `obj.categories` is ONLY destroyed when `request` is called. I really have no idea here.

Comment: @Plato I've updated the code so that every object reference is the same (`obj123`), and still it happens. I've tested, and it clears my `obj123.categories` (but everything else in `obj123`is still in tact) only after `request` is fired, before `cheerio` touches it. The earliest place I can see it happening is the callback for `resqustLink`'s `request` function. (where it says `err, resp, body` above)

Comment: @Plato I've edited the code in the question above if you care to take a look.

Comment: @robertklep See edited code above, that's as complete as I can make it. In fact, here's a dump of all the code: http://pastebin.ca/2404672 And the JSON that's being called: http://pastebin.ca/2404673 you could feasibly run that and get the exact same results (ignore the class importa as they're all copy and pasted into the script)

Comment: @Jascination remove the assignment (`storeCats.categories =`) (but not the anon function call itself) from line 46 of your first pastebin and see if that works better.